# げっそり自由 meaning?

Tags: translation, adverbs

I have this sentence in one of my N1 practice books, but I am not really sure how to translate this one:

不況のせいでリストラされたので、しばらくげっそり自由を楽しむことにした。

げっそり translate to 'being disheartened' - how to translate げっそり自由

Comment: I have not ever heard げっそり自由を楽しむ. Is it じっくり, isn't it?

Comment: Just in case you're seeing げっそり自由 as a noun phrase, げっそり is a 副詞 modifying (自由を)楽しむ.

Answer (score 3):

> 「[不況]{ふきょう}のせいでリストラされたので、しばらく（　　　）[自由]{じゆう}を[楽]{たの}しむことにした。」
>
> "Since I was laid off owing to the recession, I have decided to enjoy my freedom **~~~~ly** for a while."

There are dozens of words in Japanese that take the form of 「**〇っ〇り**」 (second kana is the small っ).  Over 95% of those are adverbs and many have an onomatopoeic quality to them.

A few **〇っ〇り**-words could certainly be used to fill in the blank in the sentence above, but unfortunately, 「**げっそり**」 is ***not*** one of them even if your book said it was.

「げっそり」 means "dejectedly", "disheartenedly", etc.  It just does not go well with the verb 「楽しむ」 = "to enjoy".  That is, unless this is supposed to be some kind of a joke.

The possible 〇っ〇り-words would include 「ゆっくり」 (leisurely)、「ひっそり」 (quietly) 、「しっかり」 (surely), etc.

Answer (score 0):

げっそり自由 is strange.こっそり自由(家族に対して) is natural. こっそり's meaning is hiding for something.げっそり is used like "げっそり痩せた".